# Absolute file path in c++ under Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I've been trying to access a given file that is always in the same location with the following C++ code:

```
if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("~/Downloads/table_scene_lms400.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
```

Since apparently the "~" is not working under C++, various posts on the internet suggest using /home/Downloads/... instead. I do not however seem to get it to work. I keep getting an error saying that the given file under above path cannot be found.

What is the correct way to access an absolute file path in C++?

Thanks very much, and sorry for the basicness of the question!

Comment: It should be `/home/budekatude/Downloads/...` or whatever your user name and home directory is.

Comment: @nwp: that did the trick! please post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution! thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shells such as bash and zsh expand `~` to the home directory. The function you used doesn't. You will have to expand it some other way. You can `cd ~` and then `pwd` to figure out where the shell thinks your home directory is and use that. Alternatively you can launch a shell and ask it for the home directory or try an environment variable or use some library such as Qt: [`QDir::homePath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath).

Answer (score 3):

`C++` runtime doesn't expand file paths. What I do is something like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

std::string const HOME = std::getenv("HOME") ? std::getenv("HOME") : ".";

std::ifstream myfile(HOME + "/path/in/home/folder.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

The tilde `~` is expanded by the *shell*, it's not a universal part of paths.

I suggest you use the environment variable `HOME` to get the path to the current users home-directory, and then append the rest of the path.